# Update limited rows in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I Have a set of data for example.

```
  A    B    C
---- ----- ----
 1   alpha  xxx    
 2    beta  vvv 
 2    beta  ccc
 2    beta  ttt
 3   Gama   zzz
```

Now I want to change the data with the same elements in column B(here beta) but with limit control

example '''update table sometable.name set B = "lamda" where B= "beta" limit 2.'''

The result that I want should look like

```
  A    B    C
---- ----- ----
 1   alpha  xxx    
 2   lamda  vvv 
 2   lamda  ccc
 2    beta  ttt
 3   Gama   zzz
```

I have tried a lot in bigquery could you please guide me. Note this is just an example and I have a large data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select * except(flag) replace(if(flag, 'lamda', B) as B)
from (
  select *, B = 'beta' and row_number() over win <= 2 as flag
  from your_table
  window win as (partition by A order by if(B = 'beta', 0, 1))
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail, Where can I find your books to construct such BigQueries from Zero to Hero?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `C` column as a join key, following seems to be possible.

```sql
MERGE INTO sample t USING (
  SELECT * FROM sample 
   WHERE B = 'beta' QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER() <= 2
) s ON t.C = s.C 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET B = 'lambda';
```

[image]